# How to reload page when cancel print command or sucess print command in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function printContent() {
  var restore = document.body.innerHTML;

  var printcontent = document.getElementById('h').innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = restore;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nikhil you might want to add some more information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
window.location.reload();
```

in `JavaScript`

Comment: I wanted to reload page when print cancel button pressed and print ok button pressed